# Does anybody know a source having multi-electrode (several channels) recorded data of multiple Neurons (I prefer real data not artificial)?

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, neurophysiology, physiology

I mean recorded data of multiple Neurons with multi-electrode. I need this data as the input for my experiment.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE! What is your demarcation between real and artificial data? What sources have you found so far which only provide artificial data?

Answer (score 3):

https://crcns.org has several openly available datasets with recordings from many different brain areas.  Each recording will likely have multiple simultaneously recorded neurons.